# Paginando um Datagridview

Tags: c#

Boa tarde...
Tenho uma datagridview que carrega varias linhas, andei pesquisando na net como posso paginar este datagridview, mas não consegui realizar tal procedimento, por não ter tanta experiencia em c#, então via aqui pedir mais uma vez a ajuda do forum para conseguir paginar o datagridview, ou seja cirar paginas no datagridview.

Segue minha tela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue o código que carrega o datagrid

```
private void ListaGrid()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand tabnet = new SqlCommand("usp_TabelaPrecosNet", conexaoDADOADV(true));
                tabnet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODTABELA", this.cb_tabela.Text);
                tabnet.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                tabnet.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(tabnet);
                DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
                dados.Fill(dtLista);

                dgw_listanet.DataSource = dtLista;

                dgw_listanet.Columns["CODPRODUTO"].HeaderText = "COD.PRODUTO";
                dgw_listanet.Columns["DESCRICAO"].HeaderText = "PROD. DESCRIÇÃO";
                dgw_listanet.Columns["IPI"].HeaderText = "% IPI";
                dgw_listanet.Columns["PRECO"].HeaderText = "PREÇO NET";
                dgw_listanet.Columns["MOEDA"].HeaderText = "TIPO MOEDA";

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não exstem dados digitados para a consulta, por favor verificar!!!");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente você devera alterar sua procedure para que retornem os valores paginados passando 2 paramentos a mais.

-Index da pagina;
-Quantidade de registros requisitados.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc_PaginadaExemplo
(
@IndexPagina int,
@QuantidadeRegistros int
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @PrimeiroRegistro int, @UltimoRegistro int

SELECT @PrimeiroRegistro = (@IndexPagina - 1) * @UltimoRegistro
SELECT @UltimoRegistro = (@IndexPagina * @QuantidadeRegistros + 1);

WITH ResultadoTemp as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY <CampoOrdenacao> DESC) as NumeroLinha,
s.<campo1>, m.<campo2>, s.<campo3>, l.<campo4> 
FROM dbo.<tabela> m
INNER JOIN dbo.<tabela2> s 
ON s.<campo1> = m.<campo2>
)
SELECT top (@UltimoRegistro-1) *
FROM ResultadoTemp
WHERE NumeroLinha > @PrimeiroRegistro 
AND NumeroLinha < @UltimoRegistro


SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

E na sua tela devera conter campos e botões para controle de paginação e quantidade de registros.

Comment: Leandro boa tarde e obrigado pela atenção, agora deixa me ver se entendi, preciso colocar todo esta query dentro da minha porcedure e isso ou tenho que criar uma nova procedure.

Comment: Voce deve implementar esses parâmetros na sua query. Em suma alterar o select do exemplo para a sua query na procedure.